# How to restrict the access of property in the UIbutton in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, getter-setter

I want to restrict some property from the exisiting class of the components.

Here is the sample code,

```
UIButton *customBtn;
property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *customBtn;
@synthesize customBtn;
```

this my implementation,

```
customBtn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 customBtn= setImage:[UIImage imageNamed"radio_button_noraml.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 customBtn= setImage:[UIImage imageNamed"radio_button_acitve.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 customBtn = CGRectMake(5, 30, 20, 20); notsupport = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 30, 290, 20)];
 [customBtn addTargetelf actionselector(MyAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.view addSubview:customBtn];
```

In my view controller, i could access all the property in the UIbutton using the customBtn.

myClass.customBtn.backGroundcolor = [UIColor blackColor];

But i want to restrict the access of the button properties,For eg.i want to access the propertybackground color and alpha value, rest of the property i don't want to access.

so please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: On way could be to subclass.

Comment: simple...dont write code for all other property....hihihihihihih...:P

Comment: you shouldn't be relying on any method to be un-callable. methods are all public, what you can do is put them in the class extension or a private header so that you get a warning when trying to call them in code... but at runtime it is still game on... you do have slightly more control over scope with ivars... but you generally dont want other classes reaching into your ivars (for encapsulation sake.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not declare the `customBtn` property in the controller's header file, instead declare only properties for those button properties that you want to publicly expose. For instance, in `MyController.h`:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController
{
}

@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor* customBtnBackgroundColor;

@end
```

Pay attention that you use the same property attributes that are in the property declaration of the original class. In the example, the button's `backgroundColor` property is actually declared by `UIView` (not `UIButton`), so if you look in `UIView.h` you will see that the property is declared with the attributes `nonatomic` and `copy`.

Next, you need to privately declare the `customBtn` property in your controller's implementation file. You also need to provide an implementation for the getter/setter methods of the properties that you exposed in the header file. The getter/setter methods simply forward the call to the actual button object. For instance, in `MyController.m`:

```
#import "MyController.h"

// Class extension with private methods and properties for MyController
@interface MyController()
  property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton* customBtn;
@end


@implementation MyController

  @synthesize customBtn;

  // Note: No need to synthesize customBtnBackgroundColor here because
  // you don't need an instance variable, and you are providing the
  // getter/setter implementation yourself.


  - (UIColor*) customBtnBackgroundColor
  {
    return self.customBtn.backgroundColor;
  }

  - (void) setCustomBtnBackgroundColor:(UIColor*)backgroundColor
  {
    self.customBtn.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
  }

@end
```

As others have written, if someone outside of `MyController` knows that a property `customBtn` exists, the property can still be accessed. The point, however, should be to define the public interface of `MyController`, and with the solution outlined above you have done as much as can be expected.

Answer (score 1):

In objective-c all methods are public, and property are nothing but setter and getter (methods).
So you can't restrict existing methods/properties.
And even if you subclass it you can only override it.
There you can add an `NSAssert` if anyone uses that method.

Comment: but you could build private properties in the class extension... `@interface MyClass ()`

Answer (score 0):

It seem you need a custom component and override the desired getters. I don't know other way to realize, maybe other will give you.

So it will not be a simple @synthesize.

The @synthesize equivalent code:

```
// .h
@property (nonatomic, retain) id ivar;

// .m
- (id)ivar {
    return ivar;
}

- (void)setIvar:(id)newValue {
    if (ivar != newValue) {  // this check is mandatory
        [ivar release];
        ivar = [newValue retain];
    }
}
```

now in the - (id)ivar should be some restrictions.

Comment: what to do if you believe that?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the thing that is missing in obj-c as I compare from C++, inheritance-modes as private, protected and public.

If these features were here your work was done, but that is not the case.

In objective C there is no private or public. Every thing is public. You can virtually not show the methods in the class interface but it still accessible for someone knowing it exists. A class inheriting from another is the sum of all the "super" class methods/attributes and it own methods/attributes (In Objective-C, one can derive from one class only, using public mode.)